# Keycloak with Outlook SMTP Server Failed to send email

Tags: java, outlook, smtp, keycloak

I have keycloak on an Azure Virtual Machine, and until a few weeks ago everything went normal, but for some storage problems I had to restart the server. After that, I can't test the SMTP connection at the Email tab.

[image: Error! Failed to send email]

If I look the logs, I see:

```
2022-05-20 00:14:47,313 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-3568) KC-SERVICES0029: Failed to send email: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 127.0.0.1, 25; timeout 10000;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
at org.keycloak.email.DefaultEmailSenderProvider.send(DefaultEmailSenderProvider.java:148)
...
```

Comment: Hello, any luck solving this issue ?

Comment: @moujib Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it, so I moved Keycloak to an Enterprise Suscription, in order to unlock port 25, and I connected it to SendGrid

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue (well I'm not an Azure, but still similar symptoms). What do you mean by "I moved Keycloak to an Enterprise Suscription, in order to unlock port 25"? It's not clear to me?

Comment: Found my problem: my keycloak server was blocking ports 25, 465 and 587 as default behaviour 

Comment: I meant to create a Linux VM in an Enterprise Suscription, then install Keycloak in it

Comment: How did you unblock them?